# Parameterized Fixture Inside unittest.TestCase class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I am using pytest to and would like to use a parameterized pytest fixture. If I don't use a class and run pytest, both tests pass, but when inside a test class, the tests both fail, but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Working Code:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def db_fixture():
    def insert_records(data):
        return data
    db = insert_records
    yield db
    db = {}  # reset fixture


def test_create_record_one(db_fixture):
    result = db_fixture({"id": 1})
    assert result == {"id": 1}


def test_create_record_two(db_fixture):
    result = db_fixture({"id": 2})
    assert result == {"id": 2}
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
import pytest
import unittest

class TestSample(unittest.TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    @pytest.fixture
    def db_fixture():
        def insert_records(data):
            return data
        db = insert_records
        yield db
        db = {}  # reset fixture

    @staticmethod
    def test_create_record_one(db_fixture):
        result = db_fixture({"id": 1})
        assert result == {"id": 1}

    @staticmethod
    def test_create_record_two(db_fixture):
        result = db_fixture({"id": 2})
        assert result == {"id": 2}
```

Error:

`TypeError: test_create_record_one() missing 1 required positional argument: 'db_fixture'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix `unittest.TestCase` with `pytest` fixtures. While `pytest` knows about `unittest` and can execute valid unit tests based on `unittest.TestCase`, the reverse is not true.

In your case, simply do not derive from `unittest.TestCase`:

```py
class TestSample:

    @staticmethod
    @pytest.fixture
    def db_fixture():
        def insert_records(data):
            return data
        db = insert_records
        yield db
        db = {}  # reset fixture

    @staticmethod
    def test_create_record_one(db_fixture):
        result = db_fixture({"id": 1})
        assert result == {"id": 1}
    ...
```